# How to add different styles to one label field using css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hi I am having a label which is having a value but I need to add different styles to that words.

```
<label> 00001 M2 Available </label>

label{
font-size:15px;
}
```

The font size 15px should be applied to 0001 only. Can anyone help me out regarding this how to achieve using css.

Comment: you should not add tags inside of label, so can you put 00001 outside of the <label> then ?

Answer (score 4):

The only way that this is possible, currently, is to wrap that first-word (or whichever other words) in a specific element and style that element:

```
<label><span>0001</span> M2 Available</label>

label span {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

You can style the [`::first-letter`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A4EyN/) and the `::first-line` pseudo-elements with CSS but, for some reason, the W3C chose not, or didn't think, to allow a `::first-word` pseudo-element.

It appears, from testing (in Chromium 28/Win XP) that using the `::first-line` pseudo-element will style the first-word (though I don't *think* this is a specified behaviour), so it might not be reliable cross-browser:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
}

label::first-line {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A4EyN/1/).

References:

- [CSS Pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements).

Comment: I should not add any tags in between.

Comment: Then this cannot be done under your use-case with CSS; it *can* be done with JavaScript (but *only* by using JavaScript to wrap the relevant word(s) with another tag and, as above, styling that tag).

Comment: Upgrade your OS :p :D

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I'm a hobbyist, and I'm running this at work (the UK's NHS) during a break. I'd *love* them to update the OS, seriously. But they'll not be doing that for a little while longer, sadly. (And at home I'm a strictly \*Nix guy; and *not* 'updating' to a non OSS OS.)

Comment: @DavidThomas I tried Linux but reverted back to W7, and ohh, so the company should upgrade them soon :) ..

Answer (score 2):

First of all, David's solution is perfect, but if you do not want to add any extra elements, than you can use `content: ""` property.. if still you can't use this, than you need to go JavaScript

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vAxs5/)

```
label.class_name:before {
    content: "00001";
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yes this approach i can achieve using content property but there is issue taht this value 0001 will keep changing everytime can we handle without hardcoding the value

Answer (score 0):

Check the js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9v2n4/

```
<label> <span style="font-size:15px">00001</span> M2 Available </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your label span with a class `<label><span class="labelItem"> 00001</span> M2 Available </label>`. then style that class .labelItem `{ font-size: 15px; }`

Comment: I'm not down-voting at the moment, but I'll draw your attention to the requirement to style *only the 00001* portion of the `label` element's text, *not* the whole of the text.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<label><p class="p01">00001</p> M2 Available</label>
```

CSS:

```
p.p01{
font-size:15px;
}
```

Comment: I should not add any tags in between the label. it should be achieved with that label only.